# Number-theoretic proof that $\pi(n) – \pi(n-\pi(n))\to\infty$

Tags: number-theory

Let $\pi(n)$ be the number of primes and $G(n)=n-\pi(n)$ the number of composites for natural number $n$.
It is easy to prove that as $n\to \infty$, $\pi(n) – \pi(G(n)) \to \infty$, if we replace $\pi(n)$ by $ n/\log(n)$.
How can we prove $\pi(n) – \pi(G(n)) \to \infty$ purely number-theoretically?

Comment: Thank you very much for the correction!

Comment: Your statement is directly implied by $p_{n+1}-p_n = o(n)$.

Answer (score 1):

Because $ \frac{x}{\ln x}(1+\frac{1}{\ln x}) \leq \pi(x) \leq \frac{x}{\ln x}(1+\frac{1.5}{\ln x})$ for all $x >600$, and $G(x)+\pi(x) = x$ so we say that $G(x)= x-\pi(x)$.

so the limits is for $\pi(n)-\pi(n-\pi(n))$ we get that when we try to minimize the result :

$$\frac{n \left(2 (\log (n)+1)-\frac{((\log (n)-1) \log (n)-1) \left(2 \log
   \left(n-\frac{n (\log (n)+1)}{\log ^2(n)}\right)+3\right)}{\log
   ^2\left(n-\frac{n (\log (n)+1)}{\log ^2(n)}\right)}\right)}{2 \log ^2(n)}$$

with simple manipulation we arrive at :
 $$ \frac{n \left(2 (\log (n)+1)-\frac{((\log (n)-1) \log (n)-1) \left(2 \log
   \left(1-\frac{\log (n)+1}{\log ^2(n)}\right)+2 \log (n)+3\right)}{\left(\log
   (n)+\log \left(1-\frac{\log (n)+1}{\log ^2(n)}\right)\right)^2}\right)}{2 \log
   ^2(n)}$$

Since $ \frac{-1}{\ln n -2} \leq \log \left(1-\frac{\log (n)+1}{\log ^2(n)}\right) \leq \frac{-1}{\ln n -1}$, substituting that in the above form we get that :

$$\frac{n \left(2 (\log (n)+1)-\frac{\left(2 \log (n)-\frac{2}{\log (n)-1}+3\right)
   ((\log (n)-1) \log (n)-1)}{\left(\log (n)-\frac{1}{\log
   (n)-2}\right)^2}\right)}{2 \log ^2(n)} $$

with little manipulation we arrive at 
$$\frac{n (\log (n) (\log (n) (\log (n) ((\log (n)-2) \log (n)-16)+41)-4)-22)}{2
   (\log (n)-1) \log ^2(n) ((\log (n)-2) \log (n)-1)^2} $$

obviously that the numerator will become positive from some point and the denominator likewise and since $n$ is in the numerator it will go to $\infty$ when $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the elaborate proof!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler, but perhaps less elementary proof because it requires some strong results on gaps between primes (it doesn't require much strength, so maybe there is an elementary proof that I'm not aware of):

We need to use the fact that the gap between primes $p_{n+1} - p_n$ is $o(p_n/\log n)$, equivalently $o(n)$.  In fact it is known (Baker-Harman-Pintz) that the prime gap is $O(p_n^{0.525})$ which is significantly smaller than we need.

$\pi(n) - \pi(G(n))$ counts the number of primes between $G(n)$ and $n$.  The length of that interval is $\Omega(n/\log n)$ by the Prime Number Theorem.  If there were only some bounded number $C$ of primes in that interval, then the average pair of consecutive primes (of size near $n$) would be $\Omega(n/C \log n)$ apart.  But this contradicts the upper bound on gaps between primes, as least for $n$ large enough.

Comment: @user1952009 I don't see that it's equivalent: I imagine there could be infinitely many gaps of size $\frac{1}{100} n$ so long as they are far apart enough that they are far enough apart that they can't accumulate in a short interval.

Comment: Yes you are right. I meant  forgetting about $\frac{n}{ \ln^k n}$ and replacing it by a relation between the gap and $\pi(n)$, so we can search for an elementary proof

Comment: @user1952009 Sure, but is there an advantage to saying $\pi(p_n)$ rather than the equivalent $n$?

Comment: Once we know $p_{n}-p_{n-1} = o(n)$ we know that $$\pi(p_n)-\pi(p_n-n) \to \infty \implies \pi(m)-\pi(m-\pi(m)) \to \infty$$

Comment: There must be an elementary proof that $p_{n+1}-p_n = o(n)$ but I can't find it

Comment: I think there is a way using the [Dickman function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickman_function)